# Firefox doesnt open webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox

When i am trying to open web page from my local server with default http or https port 80 or 443 firefox is opening properly but when i change port to some different port firefox is not opening webpage it is opening soruce code.Can anynod has idea about this?

Comment: You will have to add the port to the address `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: How is it served on other ports? Can you confirm that the headers are correct with `curl`, especially `Content-Type`?

Comment: This is happening only on firefox broeser IE i am able to open page in any port.And also when i give port other 80 or 443 in url .pageinfo is showing content type as plain/text but in 80 port it shows plain/html

Comment: Seems Firefox is doing the sane thing here and interpreting the content-type. It looks like IE is just trying to interpret whatever it seems as HTML, and got lucky. _Probably_ your server is configured/written to serve other ports as plaintext, and only 80/443 as plain/html. Can you confirm this?